# How to check if string is query? Protect from sql injection;

Tags: sql, spring, hibernate, jpa, sql-injection

I use Spring + Hibernate.
In one part I have native sql like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (...) sel
WHERE %s
```

%s i receive from UI. It looks like "id = ?1 AND name = ?2..." + list of params.
It is generated by query builder;

And now i have a case when UI can send something like:
CLAUSE: id = 'id; TRUNCATE TABLE schema.foo;'

How to check that clause is not a query?
Where can i find some libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take an other direction : rather than trying to detect if a query is malicious, make sure that the query cannot do anything malicous, with grants at database level :

if you have a public table, with users generating queries for this table, create a database user that can only SELECT on this sole table, and use a specific jdbc connection, that connect to the database using the former read-only user, to run these 'unsafe' queries.

Comment: That sounds good. I can give write rules for user only on user_settings table.
Thanks a lot. I looked for this issue from another side.